TextField, update riverpod state in onChanged
I have this flutter code:
TextField(
  controller: item.controller,
  style: const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 18.0,
  ),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Enter header',
    border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    ref
        .read(elementListProvider.notifier)
        .updateItem(index, value: newValue);
  },
),

There are multiple TextField being build by a ReorderableListView.
Currently, when I type, I can type 1 character before the focus is shifted to the next text field. If I remove the ref.read(....); line, then everything works fine. I can even have a print statement here and it works fine. My issue only occur when trying to update my riverpod state here.
This is the updateItem function in my provider:
  void updateItem(int index,
      {String? value, String? amount, String? unit, bool? isRangeEnabled}) {
    var item = state[index];
    var updatedItem = item.copy()
      ..value = value ?? item.value
      ..amount = amount ?? item.amount
      ..unit = unit ?? item.unit
      ..isRangeEnabled = isRangeEnabled ?? item.isRangeEnabled;
    state = [
      ...state.sublist(0, index),
      updatedItem,
      ...state.sublist(index + 1),
    ];
  }

I have also tried to use onSubmitted indead and that one works fine, except for the issue that, if the user press the next TextField (or android back button) without pressing the "done" key on their keyboard, the state is not saved and therefore not sent to the backend.
Therefore, what I need is that OnChanged + ref.... does not remove the focus and allow the user to continue typing. I have tried all kinds of things chatGPT suggested but nothing worked, it just shifted the problem slightly (eg debouce just delayed the issue, focusNode made it loose focus from all TextFields instead of moving to the next one etc.). I need help solving this and I am completely stuck for days :(
Thank you for trying to save me from this never ending nightmare

Just a quick glance, but I'd use family providers, passing in their index as the family key.  That way, they each have their own lifecycle, and updating one won't force a redraw of another.

The same happens without riverpod too, using normal callbacks and setState ends up in the same issue. Will update if I find a solution to this!
